# Wordpress SQL Query in URL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, url

```
$args = array(
        "post_type" => "-=your custom post type==-",
        "meta_query" => array (
            array (
              "key" => "quality",
              "value" => "hd",
              "compare" => "IN"
            )
          ) 
    );
$result = new WP_Query($args);
```

Is there any way to do the same thing with the url. for example www.example.com/?post_type=post&meta_key=quality&meta_key=hd

Comment: Have you tried reading a PHP 101 tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

To get input data from URL, we use variable $_GET in php.

Read more: 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

So for a URL with key=values like this: www.example.com/?post_type=post&meta_key=quality&meta_value=hd

We can catch the values as following and store in variables:

```
$p_type = $_GET['post_type'];
$meta_key = $_GET['meta_key'];
$meta_val = $_GET['meta_value'];
```

Now we can pass those variables into the query:

```
$args = array(
    "post_type" => $p_type,
    "meta_query" => array (
        array (
          "key" => $meta_key,
          "value" => $meta_val,
          "compare" => "IN"
        )
      ) 
);
$result = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: This sorts my wordpress posts.... I have added them to my post template page in wordpress... but I want to sort them with URL parameters..